# Committing changes to Lucene index v2.3 corrupts it - unknown index format -11

Tags: lucene, sitecore, luke

I'm interested in editing the search index for a Sitecore (6.5) installation. So far I have used Luke from version 1.0.0 and 3.1.0 to open the index folder. Luke reports the following details

This was done with lukeall-3.1.0.jar

```
Index format: -4 (Lucene 2.3)
Index functionality: lock-less, single norms file, shared doc store
```

I attempt to commit a simple change to the index via the Luke GUI ie. Right Click Set Norm then change 0.5 to 0.1. I reopen the index and it now says

```
Index format: -11 (Lucene 1.3 or prior)
Index functionality: unknown
```

This index format is now incompatible with Sitecore - is there anyway to commit a change to the index and preserve its version?

Thanks!

Comment: Sitecore 6 is [buggy with Luke](http://seankearney.com/post/Using-Luke-to-view-Lucene-indexes-in-Sitecore-6), no problems with [Sitecore 7/Lucene 3 though](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/Getting-to-Know-Sitecore/Posts/2013/06/Using-Luke-to-Understand-Sitecore-7-Search.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason you're not using Sitecore to handle the indexing?  Sitecore is REALLY REALLY picky with Lucene and the specific Lucene version it uses.  It pretty much handles all it's own indexing and expects specific versions. In Sitecore 7, it actually drives most aspects of how the Sitecore client works too.  I'm not familiar with Luke, but unless this is something outside of Sitecore or unless you're really good with Sitecore, you're probably going to run into lots of issues trying to integrate versions of Lucene that differ from the Lucene version that is referenced by the Sitecore Kernel assembly.

Oh and I should also add that there is a whole section in the web.config that manages the indexes.. or if you want, you can install one of the extended search modules.  They all work quite nicely.

Comment: I found no issue with how Sitecore uses Lucene in building it's index and you're right the config is the place for setting the rules, in my opinion the reporting and analysis seems a bit unrepresented. The lucene index viewer modules for Sitecore are unspeakably bad so I decided to assess Luke as a diagnostic/analysis tool .This is not something I would use for production just a way of assessing score changes, running queries - a bit of research etc.